# How to segregate a single value from a query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

My apologies but I am a bit lost in the world of Microsoft Access. So I currently have a query that returns a column of values. The output looks like this:

`SMABranchCode
    Code1
    Code2
    Code3
    etc.`

This query then gets moved to a form text box. To do this, I have used Control Source like so:
    `=IIf(IsNull(DLookUp("SMABranchCode","PWS_SM_QUERY"))," ","X")`

This works "Ok"; however there are going to be probably 30+ more text boxes going horizontally next to this one all running the same query. Above them is a label with the Code. So basically when it spits out the data it looks like this (as long as there is an entry for that code):

Code 1  |  Code 2  | Code 3

X   |     X    |   X

The problem is, I either need to go and create a query for each of these text boxes so that it only pulls a single entry for each Code OR I can hopefully change up my Control Source entry (=IIf(IsNull(DLookUp("SMABranchCode","PWS_SM_QUERY"))," ","X")) to include criteria so that each text box has its own Criteria, so that from the one original query, each Code (1,2,3) only displays its information.

I have tried changing DLookUp to have criteria which has looked like this:
   `=IIf(IsNull(DLookUp("SMABranchCode","PWS_SM_QUERY","SMABranchCode = Code1"))," ","X")`

However that gives me an #Error! in the boxes I apply it too. I'm hoping maybe someone can help me figure out a solution since my brain is turning to mush over this.

Thank you

Comment: Is this on a form or report? Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? Domain aggregate functions can perform slowly on form and report objects.

Comment: There is almost certainly a much better way to go about all this, but for any meaningful help you have to go a step back and show your table structure and what you hope to accomplice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume SMABranchCode is a text type field. Criteria values for text fields must be delimited with apostrophes, date/time field values would use #.

`"SMABranchCode = 'Code1'"`

Comment: I don't know how I missed that - thank you very much